# Copy paste from one form to other c#

Tags: c#

What im trying to do:

1. Search products by BarCode on `Form1` form;
2. if it cannot be found:
       1. Open `Inventory` form 
       2. Search product by name or description
       3. On `ListView click` on the found product copy its BarCode and paste it to the `Form1` barcode textbox.

All that is done corectly. The problem is that every time I add product from `Inventory` form a *new* `Form1` is opened.

The values are not processed in the same `Form1`, so assume I sell 4 products:

- 2 of them are added through `Form1` barcode search
- 2 of them are added through `Inventory` search form

In the end I get 3 opened `Form1` forms, one with 2 products and two forms with single product (added through `Inventory` form). I need them to be all in one.

Thanks

//-------------------------Form1--------------------------------------------

```
private void btnInventory_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {
        Inventory Inventory = new Inventory();
        Inventory.Show();
    }



 private string _theValue;

    public string TheValue
    {
        get
        {
            return _theValue;
        }
        set
        {
            _theValue = value;
            txtItems.Text = value;

        }
    }
```

//-----------------------------Inventory---------------------------------

```
private void ShowForm1()
    {

        string value = label9.Text;
        Form1 newForm = new Form1();
        newForm.TheValue = value;
        this.Close();
        newForm.ShowDialog();
    }



private void lvList_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {
        label9.Text = lvList.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[0].Text;
        this.ShowForm1();

    }
```

---

***Im sorry for the delay, i had to wait 8h before posting again***

Thanks for ur reply.

I just tried that
**Form1**

```
  private void btnInventory_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {

         Inventory _inv = new Inventory();
         if (DialogResult.OK == _inv.ShowDialog())
             {
                 txtItems.Text = _inv.fugi;
             }

     }
```

**and in Inventory Form**

```
private string test;
        public string fugi
        {
            get { return test; }
            set { test = label9.Text; }
        }



private void lvList_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            label9.Text = lvList.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[0].Text;
            this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
            this.Close();


        }
```

**txtItems.Text** does not get the value of **test** from inventory form

Comment: Please check my updated answer, you may find that you are able to post comments to my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its opening a new dialog because you tell it to in `ShowForm1`, Personally I would change your btnInventory click as follows

```
private void btnInventory_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Inventory _inv = new Inventory();
    if(DialogResult.OK == Inventory.ShowDialog())
    {
          valueIWantToSet = _inv.Accessor;
    }
}
```

Accessor you will need to make yourself similar to

```
public TypeOfVar Accessor
{
    get{return m_privateVariableThatIWillMakeAndSetToMyBarcode;}
}
```

Edit: 
Once you have gotten the value of your barcode you need to set `DialogResult` as Follows

```
 this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
```

and then set the variable you wish to access to the barcode before closing your form

Edit2:
Your `ShowForm1` will end up similar to this (May want to rename this method!)

```
{
this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
m_myVar = SelectedItem..;
this.Close;
}
```

**UPDATE ANSWER**

You are still having problems as you haven't used the `set` property correctly, your get is fine as it is. There is a keyword in c# called `value` that should be used for setters. this value will take the value of whatever is on the right hand side of an = sign.. you can think of it like this...

`fugi = label9.Text`

In the above line, `fugi` is using your properties getter in order to get the value that needs to be set to `label9.Text`. The `=` sign says that you intend to use the setter for this property and set the value of `value` to `label9.Text`.

Properties with a getter and setter are used so you do not have to provide access to the underlying variable to somewhere you would not like to and then can have the option to just set or get this variable as needed.

This means that your problem persists have you have yet to set the value of `test`, it is still the default string value.
So you have a couple of ways to solve your problem.

The first way is just to provide a getter for label9.Text and remove the need for your private variable.

```
public string Fugi //Properties should really start with capital letter
{
    get{return label9.Text;}
}
```

The second is to set the value of test before you call your getter in btnInventoryClick and remove the setter method

```
private void lvList_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   test = label9.Text;
```

and the third ist to set `test` as shown in method 2 but also change the set method of Fugi to the following to allow this test variable to be set elsewhere.

`set{text = value;}`